# EF Database First schema deployment during application runtime?

Tags: entity-framework

The question is - **Whats the best way to automatize database schema deployment when using EF6 DB-First approach?**

Is it even possible to create or update existing database-side schema on application runtime? Is there any alternative to manual script execution?
Usually I work with NHibernate and I'm enjoying one-code-line schema deployment.

Comment: a DbContext has an "Initialization strategy", which will basically tell EF what to do if the schema of the database does not match its model. This will be done automatically.